# How much hp would you trade for a magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

5th edition
I'm thinking of making a supernatural marketplace were players can trade for/with anything. One merchant would trade max hp for magical items and I'm not sure what would be an appropriate trade.
The price depends on the hit dice of the player. The hit dice and hp will be lost barring a wish or divine intervention. (Consequences depending on how the gp is returned).
Player levels would hopefully be between 5 and 10, high enough that they will be wanting magic but low enough that the hit dice lost would be of importance.

Comment: What game (and edition) are you playing?

Comment: Hi Red Paladin, and welcome to the site! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Please note we cater to hundreds of different tabletop games and editions. As Thomas asks, we need to know what you're playing in order to answer this question.

Comment: I feel like there are details missing as well, such as what scale should be used to make such a conversion. Are you comparing it to the value of magic items? Magic Items that would increase HP or just any in general? Are you looking for characters to feel like it was a good investment (e.g. increase their damage output by more than the lost HP) or ultimately regret it (find out that the world really is much more dangerous)? If they regret it, how hard do you expect it to be to regain those HP?

Comment: You say the hp traded are based on the class. What do you mean by this? Are a barbarian's hit points worth double, same as, or half that of a wizard? Is there some maximum (other than reducing yourself to 0 max) that can be spent?

Comment: Is this permanent maximum HP or just a one off hit? Do you lose a hit dice as well? Can you take the average in the same way you do when you level up, or do you have to roll?

Comment: Are you suggesting that if a character completes this deal they can undo the costs of it with a Wish spell or Divine Intervention? If they do so, will the magic item they bought lose it's magic? What level are the players that you're proposing to participate in this market and are these avenues of undoing their costs readily accessible to them?

Answer (score 5):

#### There isn't even a well defined relationship between magic items and money.

You ask how to correlate hit points and money for the purpose of trading for magic items. Unfortunately, I really don't think that can work, because *there isn't even a well defined relationship between magic items and money.* The *Dungeon Master's Guide* assigns unhelpfully broad ranges to the value of items within each rarity category:

| Rarity | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Common | 50-100 gp |
| Uncommon | 101-500 gp |
| Rare | 501-5,000 gp |
| Very Rare | 5,001-50,000 gp |
| Legendary | 50,001+ gp |

When assigning value to a particular magic item, *this is the full extent of the guidance provided*, so you are already just guessing based on how strong you think the item is relative to other items in the same rarity category. It simply isn't an objective or calculated system.

Trying to then establish an exchange rate between a non-renewable resource like max hit points and money just further confounds an already undefined system. There is just no way to do this that isn't totally guessing, because we are already guessing before we introduce hit-points-as-currency, and as you have observed, different class will value their hit points differently because of how much they have and what they use them for. I would just advise against using this system at all, because there is simply no way of knowing how it will work out until after a player decides they feel cheated by the trade.

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct, but its worth noting that in the real world, value can very much be in the eye of the beholder and very hard to pin down.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer states, converting maxHP (not just HP) to gold is firmly in homebrew territory. Thomas Markov gives an overview of the price range of various magic items. I'll try to give an idea of the budget each character has over the course of his life.

But one thing that will become obvious is that a conversion from maxHP to gold is pretty fuzzy, but a conversion from maxHP to magic item is more feasable. And since you're in homebrew territory, maybe not trying to be too exact is a good idea.

## Some background concepts

### Hit dice (the old way)

Before 4e, there was the concept of "hit die" (HD) as a measure of power. This was an approximation of the number of HP a creature has, but also of it's level and overall abilities. When a level 1 character grew to level 2, he was considered to move from a 1HD creature to a 2HD creature.

A human bandit was a 1HD monster,  but the bandit captain likely was likely to be a 3HD creature because it was more experienced (also because he would be a boss monster for the players). By comparison, a [Giant Boar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16876-giant-boar) is a CR2 monster with 5d10 HP, making it a 5HD monster.

This concept is still present in 5e, but it's expressed either with direct hitpoints or with challenge rating (CR) for monsters.
For example, back in AD&D, sleep would affect a number of HD (or all creature below 5HD, if you go even further). In 5e, the spell affect a number of HP.

Nevertheless, I will use a similar approximation to gauge how much a level worth of HP is worth in gold. First because it allows to see characters as having only a few things to offer(a level 5 character only has 5 level to give). Second because, as you mention in your question, you want to give different value to the health of different classes. And seeing the world in HD makes it easier change the price depending on character.

### On average, one level is worth 7 HP

Here's the essence of the math I use when balancing traps and encounters. I've found that my life is a lot easier when I count HP and damage in hit die than hit points.

Over half the classes get 1d8 HP per level. For simplicity, I will use the 1d8 as the default HD for all characters. The average of 1d8 is around 5.

I also expect the average player character to have a +2 bonus to his constitution (that's 14 or 15 if you prefer the ability score instead of the bonus) which is added at every level. This is less obvious, but in my experience with D&D-like game, this is the case if you let the players choose their stats. Constitution is the third or second most useful stat for every character build I've seen. WHen given the choice of point-buy, most people will raise the stat to +2 unless they accept they'll be squishier than the rest of the group.

From both of those points, I'll assume one level is worth 7HP on average. If you want to consider the size of each classe's HD, then you get the following table (assuming constitution bonus of +2).

| Wizard | Sorcerer | 1d8 class | Fighter | Ranger | Paladin | Barbarian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1d6+2 | 1d6+2 | 1d8+2 | 1d10+2 | 1d10+2 | 1d10+2 | 1d12+2 |
| 6 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 9 |

From there, just choose how many item you expect a normal character to get and how many HD you expect players to give up and compute accordingly. That's technically an answer, but also not really useful.

## Value of a magic item

The Dungeon Master's Guide give rough idea of what the appropriate level is for each rarity of item (In Chapter7 "Treasure" in the section on magic item). But that does not tell us if you will also give magic items as a GM, or how many magic items characters are expected to buy.

| Rarity | Character Level | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Common | 1st or higher | 50–100 gp |
| Uncommon | 1st or higher | 101–500 gp |
| Rare | 5th or higher | 501–5,000 gp |
| Very rare | 11th or higher | 5,001–50,000 gp |
| Legendary | 17th or higher | 50,001+ gp |

### How much are you willing to make your players pay?

From this, how many HD do you expect your players to give up? How hard are your combats? Do you finish off uncouncious characters? How powerful are those magic items? How important is combat anyway?

So I'm going to assume that the characters always have bought 1 of the best item they can. And possibly refunded (can you sell back the item in exchange for your lost HD?) or traded the rest. If that doesn't work for you, you'll have to do the work by yourself.

### Looking at some CR5 monsters

Looking at a CR5 monster, the [Fire Elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16861-fire-elemental) does 4d6+6 (+1d10) damage per turn while the [Earth Elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16853-earth-elemental) does 4d8+10. This is good, the Earth Elemental does approximately 4HD worth of damage in a turn if everything connects ( 4d8+10 is approximately 4x(1d8+2) ). Your players willhave 5HD worth of HP at this point, so a single HD worth of magic item puts a character at risk of going down in a single turn (if he is not a fighter/ranger/paladin/barbarian).

In the real world, I would expect half of the hit to miss, so that's 2HD worth of damage. That seems really really low for my taste, so I would be happy with the players spending 2 or 3 HD on magic items at that level. But my combat is lethal. If you care about keeping your players alive, you'll want to adjust the price of a magic item based on that. Hopefully, by seeing the characters as spending level instead of maxHP, this will be easier.

Trying to get a conversion from HD to gold, the ranges are huge. So huge it makes them meaningless. Between level 5 and 10, the value of a hit die can vary between 250 and 2000gp if you use the values I propose below. For this reason, I won't even show them.

## Conclusions

### Forget gold value, aim for magic item value

One thing I realized while looking at the table above is that the gold conversion makes no sense. For this reason, setup your magic merchant as trading purely in hit point (vitae? life force?) and not at all in gold.

From there, I'd suggest you set price range for different items and  eyeball it. Uncommon items are the best you can get between level 1 and 5? Then a good uncommon item should cost as much as a level 5 character is willing to pay.

As an example, here is what I'd do. Keeping in mind that this is absolutely untested. I provide this just as a framework for you to make up your own mind.

| Rarity | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Common | <1HD* |
| Uncommon | 1HD |
| Rare | 1-3HD |
| Very rare | 3-5HD |
| Legendary | ???** |

A few notes :

- Common items would probably be bought with gold or bought in bulk. 3 for 1HD.
- Legendary items are pretty damn powerful and the stuff of legends between gamers. I don't think you should be able to buy them. For example, one such item is a ring of wish that could refund the price paid to obtain the ring.

### Be careful of loss aversion

Keep in mind how your player will react to premanently loosing 10+ maxHP permanently. There is a phenomenon called [Loss Aversion Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion) that points out that people feel the loss deeper than the wins. Maybe your players will consider even 5HP to be a high price for a magic item, let alone 3 level worth of HP!

A price may be mathematically sound on paper, but felt as very unfair in play. Remember, your players (likely) don't know how easy/tough your battles are. They also probably don't see their characters as having "2 HD they don't really need to win everything", every single HitPoint can mean life or death!

For this reason, it can be a good idea to... just wing it with a vague guideline of how expensive an item should be. The game is very much not balanced and it's usually unbalanced in the player's favor. Let them pick their poison, die if they make bad choices. Remember that the death saves mecanics are pretty lenient. It's fine if people drop to 0HP at the end of a fight.